# Have wiring diagrams been generalized to arbitrary digraphs?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations, coxeter-groups

A "combinatorial wiring diagram" is a way to define a permutation by a drawing of a particular planar digraph.  For example, this wiring diagram corresponds to the permutation $(3412)$:
[image]

In Coxeter combinatorics it is common to study the properties of reduced wiring diagrams, where no two wires cross twice (one could "reduce" such a diagram by shuffling around the wires to remove these crossings).

One way to view such a diagram (which will be relevant to my question) is by a "gluing-and-rerouting" of the identity diagram.  In particular, start with the identity wiring diagram:

[image]

Then glue together adjacent paths at a few points:[image]

And finally "reroute" each path by having it swap places with the other path at each "glue point," giving the initial wiring diagram at the beginning of this post.

> **My Question:** I am curious about a generalization of wiring diagrams in which we drop the restriction that only adjacent paths can be glued together, instead allowing our paths to be glued in an arbitrary combinatorial pattern (which probably does not have a nice embedding in the plane).  The restriction that each "glue point" contains exactly two paths is maintained, and thus a permutation is uniquely defined in the "rerouting step."
>
> Intuitively, we can think of these "generalized wiring diagrams" as a version of wiring diagrams, where the part of the diagram inside the box can be *any* digraph rather than just a planar digraph.
>
> Have these been studied?

Like for the original problem, I am interested in the structural properties of reduced diagrams, meaning that no set of "glue points" may be deleted while still defining the same permutation.  At first glance, this seems to be a harder problem than for usual wiring diagrams, as there exist reducible structures in generalized wiring diagrams in which two paths still only intersect once (whereas every reducible classical wiring diagram has a pair of paths that intersect twice).

Comment: This sounds like you're talking about factorizations of permutations into transpositions (not just simple transpositions any more, but arbitrary transpositions). They appear in the literature here and there: e.g., Lemme 4.16 in http://user.math.uzh.ch/feray/Peccot/ApprocheDualeVFeray.pdf , or https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05969v2 .

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think this is *nearly* my question, but not quite.  My question would correspond to factorizing permutations into transpositions if the inner graph was constrained to be acyclic.  However, the possible presence of directed cycles in the inner graph means that you won't necessarily be able to write out the graph as a linearly-ordered composition of swaps.

Comment: Oh! I for some reason assumed that the intersections are linearly ordered from left to right. The general case of graphs is subtler -- I don't even know right off the bat how to combinatorially formalize it.